# Failure in importing Google Map on Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to import the following to the Andriod Studio. But in every line, "android" is in red, indicating that the importing is not successful.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Also when I try to use write:

```
private LatLng position = null;
```

It also shows the "LatLng" in red, indicating the previous importing is not successful. How can I import the Google Map correctly?

Comment: Have you added the Google Play Services to the Grandle file? (build.gradle)

Comment: Did you add the Google Play services package to your project? Step 2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_1_download_android_studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies{
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Then of course in your AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

These are the permissions you might need!

Then add the required meta-data to the same AndroidManifest file:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="YourApiKeyHere"/>
```

**EDIT**

Please add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file;

```
<permission
    android:name="yourapppackagenamehere.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

I should note that the **google_play_services_version** integer value is automatically available to you so you just need to point to it without having to add it yourself. I would clean the problem and try again please!

Once you have done this, your project should have the required pieces to work with Google Maps!

I hope this helps you! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do all of the above. And the only problem I have is when I was doing <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />        "@integer/google_play_services_version" is in red as well. It says "Validates resource references in Andriod XML files"

Comment: So you updated your build.gradle file and then syncronized the dependencies?

Comment: Please look at the changes I have added then remember to clean your project and see if that helps!